# How to create permanent linux network namespace

Tags: linux-networking, iproute2, network-namespace

I know that `ip netns add xxx` command can be used to create a linux network namespace, but it is not permanent, meaning after server reboot the created namespace will be gone.

Then how can I create a permanent one which can survive server reboot?

Comment: What is the distribution? On debian and derivatives you could just add this to `/etc/network/interfaces` or even use `if-up.d`.

Answer (score 5):

Network namespaces are not persistent across system restarts. You will need to create a script that is run at startup and arrange to have it run.

How you cause it to run depends on  your needs, you may be able to cal it from /etc/rc.local or you may be able to hook it into some other script. You may find that you need to hook it into the init system (init scripts/systemd etc) for your (unnamed) OS/Distro.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/unshare.1.html) you can define a file to create a permanent namespace, thus instead of using `ip netns` you want to use `unshare --net=/my/permanent/netns sh`.